# limit Sudo (or other access) to one alternate user account?

Tags: security, sudo

Is it possible to use sudo or some other mechanism to allow a user to only have access to running commands under another specific user account? (i.e. not root?)

I have to provide some level of administrative access over a web tool running under the shell-less account www-data. But on occasion it might be useful for them to be able to run programs as 'www-data' for doing administrative work on the web server. I'm not sure how to allow that while restricting their access to root or other services.

Comment: Have `www-data` own those programs, and enable the setuid bit on them.

Comment: OK, but what programs? The [need for] access isn't limited to a single command but to a set of files/directory tree and a handful of services (http/mysql/php). If they needed to restart the server, I could create a script and set-uid it, but I don't know what other things they might need to do. (run tar, create files, copy files, move files, etc)

Comment: I was merely referring to the programs to which _you_ referred in the question.  If they are system tools, then this is what `sudo` already exists to handle.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it is possible to do this with `sudo`. From the `sudoers` man page:

```
A Runas_Spec sets the default for the commands that follow it.  What this
 means is that for the entry:

 dgb     boulder = (operator) /bin/ls, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/lprm

 The user dgb may run /bin/ls, /bin/kill, and /usr/bin/lprm—but only as
 operator.
```

Comment: The sudoers man page: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sudo/sudoers.5.en.html